# Is this random effects crossed design correct in my GLMM?

Tags: mixed-model, repeated-measures, modeling, random-effects-model, glmm

I am confused about how random effects are structured in my model. I've read the discussion about it [Crossed vs nested random effects: how do they differ and how are they specified correctly in lme4?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/228800/crossed-vs-nested-random-effects-how-do-they-differ-and-how-are-they-specified/228814#228814). But I'm still having doubts.

I measured the response in plants as Duration [in seconds] at two Ages [young and old] using the same plants. So, I think it's a repeated measures design with crossed random effects, because the same individuals were measured two times, first at T1, then at T2. I assumed it is not nested, because subjects are not independently measured at Age.
[image: My experimental design]

My data:

| plantID | Age | Duration | Nleaves.plant |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Young | 1.33 | 18 |
| 1 | Old | 2.64 | 75 |
| 2 | Young | 4.68 | 14 |
| 2 | Old | 4.99 | 56 |
| 3 | Young | 3.34 | 26 |
| 3 | Old | 3.75 | 94 |

I think that I have a crossed design, so a model like this would be appropriate:

> m <- glmmTMB(Duration~ Age+ Nleaves.plant +(1|plantID) + (1|Age), data=df, family = Gamma("log"))

But I also was wondering if this model is correct as well:

> m2 <- glmmTMB(Duration~ Age+ Nleaves.plant + (Age|plantID), data=df, family = Gamma("log"))

My questions are:

1. Which model is correctly specified?

Sorry about this question, I know that it has been adressed many times in this forum, but I am still confused on this topic.
Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first model:

```
Duration~ Age+ Nleaves.plant +(1|plantID) + (1|Age)
```

...does not make sense because `Age` has only 2 levels plus it appears to be of primary interest in your research question. So it should be a fixed effect.

The 2nd model makes sense, provided that random slopes ate supported by the data.

Comment: Thank you for your response and time. I think you are right, it makes more sense to fit a model with random slopes and intercepts.